# CSS different unhover animation (CSS Zen Garden Example)

Tags: css, css-animations

Just saw this CSS-only animation on http://csszengarden.com/219/, and wanted to recreate the animation, which starts when you hover over the middle card i.e.

Normally the site provides a CSS stylesheet, but on this example I couldn't find any.

The hover animation part was just an animation which first translated the y-axis and then changed the perspective.

My problem is that I don't really know how the unhover part of this animation is working because first the card has to keep the end state of the hoveranimation and then it first translate on the y-axis and then it zooms out so it's not a reversed animation of the hovering.

It tried the approach of keyframes with `from` and `to`. This approach could start the unhoveranimation with the right end state of the hover, but it only can handle a single animation and not animations which are sequential. Moreover with using `from` and `to` the animation just jumps when you unhover before the animation ended.

**Here is what i've got so far.**

```css
.parent {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  left: 40%;
  border: medium solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

.parent:hover .child{
  animation: 3s in forwards;
}

@keyframes in {
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 100px, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(0px, 100px, 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you visit the given website, make sure your resolution is big enough (or just scroll out)! Otherwise it may be confusing.

Comment: @Bouvanni I looked at your post and also tried this approach but it only works with single animations which do not have several animation steps isn't it?

Comment: After I looked into the CSS of the page, it looks like they are just using delays for some transitions. The moving vie `right` for example happens immediately 1s long. The `transform` property has a delay of 1s so it begins after the banner has moved down etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `:hover` multiple styling properties are changed. The `transition` property can have a delay value like `transition: property duration timing delay`. In your example some properties have a delay and some don't so it looks like there are multiple transitions happening. Below is an example with changing `left` and `top` of a `div`. The `left` property has a delay of 1 second, `top` has no delay.

```css
.banner {
  transition: top 1s linear, left 1s linear 1s;
  /*when hovered, move 100 down, after 1s move 100 right*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: coral;
}

.banner:hover {
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}


/*this is needed so you don't get flickering*/

.banner::before {
  content: '';
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">Hello Stackoverflow!</div>
```